# How do you use a URL string to update an ImageView?

Tags: android, url, imageview, picasso

I made an Android app that has a child Activity with an ImageView.
The Child is passed a String url from the parent using an Intent bundle.
I need to use that String to update my ImageView but I'm unsure what the best way to do this is.  After doing some research I came across an API called Picasso which handles strings and sends them to an ImageView.

The format they use is...

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

However I don't see a way to load the context of my Activity.
Is there a call I need to make to get the context somehow?

All examples I've found seem to use an ArrayAdapter and call it within the getView() method.  I can't do this because it's an Activity, not an Adapter Class.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a call I need to make to get the context somehow?

`Activity` inherits from `Context`. Use `this` to reference the `Context`:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```